# Repeating terms of a given sentence

Tags: code-golf, string

**Program**

Write a program to display repeating terms of a given sentence.

**Explanation**

The program must output the repeating terms of two or more letters from the given input (input is a sentence separated by spaces without any punctuation except the full-stop indicating the end.)  Repeated terms may not span across or include a space. For example, if input is the sentence "I **am** **an** **am**eture **ma**the**ma**gici**an**" the output must be am, ma, an. (note that "em" is not a valid output as it is separated by space).

Repeated terms may overlap with each other. For example if the input is "ababa", the output should include "aba", even though the two instances of it overlap.

```
ababa
aba
  aba
```

**Example**

Input:

> International competitions are better than intercollege ones.

Output:

> Inter, ti, er, tion, io, on, ion, tio, co, on, .......etc
> (t, l must not be included as they are 1 letter.) (Upper lower Cases do not matter)

**Test cases**

```
aabcde cdec -> cde, cd, de

aab aacab -> aa, ab

aaa aabcaaa ababa -> aaa, aa, ab, aba, ba

abababa-> ab, aba, abab, ababa, ba, bab, baba
```

**Winning Criterion**

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21964/101710  --sandboxed

Comment: I'm going to VTC because this isn't really clear enough. There's no point using the sandbox if you're not going to address the feedback. I'd recommend reading through the [Things to avoid when writing challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8047) page.

Comment: Suggested test case: `abababa`, which I think should result in `ab, aba, abab, ababa, ba, bab, baba`. BTW, can you confirm that overlapping matches must be taken into account? (This is the only way to match `aba` in the last test case.)

Comment: thanks edited accordingly

Comment: Note that adding test cases is not the same as adding explanation.  Both are nice but the latter is what is needed to clarify a question.

Comment: I've made some edits to clarify this based on your test cases.  I can't be sure that this is what you meant, so feel free to roll back.  But I would like this question to address the order of the outputted terms.  Does the order matter?  If it does matter what order should they be in?

Comment: @WheatWizard order doesn't matter. .Thanks a lot for the support and helpful edits.

Comment: I think the case insensitivity should be mentioned in more than an example. I'd edit it myself, but I'm unclear what's intended. Can the output strings be in any case even if they don't appear in that form in the sentence? Might the input be capitalized in more than its first letter? You could also change it to be case sensitive instead or guarantee the input is lowercase.

Comment: @xnor, thanks for pointing it out. Case sensitivity does not matter at all in either input or output..

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES10), 99 bytes

```javascript
s=>new Set([...s].map((q,i,a,j=i)=>a.map(_=>s.lastIndexOf(q+=s[++i])>j&!/ /.test(q)?q:[])).flat(2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY0/C8IwEMV3P0XsIDkaU3AUUmcnB8dS5CVNpaX2jwnqt69NHBx6x7s7Hu/HtXjBmWcz@n0/VHau1exU3ts3u1rPCymlK@UDI@eTaAREqxpSOaJ1U7mTHZw/95X9XGo@pcoVadqUlLe7bcYy6a3zfKLTdCxKIll38PxANJuhd0NnZTfcec0TQJvKskUmIWK/yrJgiGUIVtnNGmGAgf4DEQEEg16nwcKTuPXSgYrpEI9I0HJozF8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 119 bytes

```python
lambda s:{''.join(y) for x in range(2,len(s))for y in permutations(s,x)if s.count(''.join(y))>1}
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RczBCsIwDIDhu08RdlkrY6DeBH0SL9lsNbImJc1gQ3z26k5eP37@vNpT@FTj5VYnTMMdoZzfbdu/hNitHqIoLEAMivwI7thNgV3xfvN18xw0zYZGwsWVbvEUofSjzGzu//HXw2cXVRKQBTWRqQClLGr7mpV@bXQN4gCIIw6N9/UL)

Extremely slow... Works by calculating permutations

Comment: This is not matching `aba` in `ababa` and would therefore fail on the last test case. (Unless this test case is invalid and overlapping matches should not be taken into account.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-g`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ã køS fÅü lÉ y
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWc&code=4yBr%2bFMgZsX8IGzJIHk&input=ImFhYSBhYWJjYWFhIGFiYWJhIgotUQ)

- saved 4 thanks to @Shaggy

```
    ã       - substrings
    køS     - remove if contains space
    fÅ     - take longer than 1
    ü       - sort and group
    lÊ     - take groups longer than 1
    y      - transpose
    -g flag to return first element
```

Comment: 15 bytes, with the `-g` flag: `ã køS lÉ ü lÉ y`

Comment: 14: `ã køS fÅü lÉ y`

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! I don't know why I though about the l-1 method but I didn't considered because of empty lists resulting in -1 hence not False o.O